# How to resolve this issue in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-development-server

While setting up MongoDB I'm getting this error again and again.

I've tried by deleting data(where data has to be stored) and mongod directory and tried installing it again. but the error still remains.

```sh
$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
$ ./mongod
```

### Error Message

> Error parsing command line: the argument for option '--bind_ip' should
>   follow immediately after the equal sign try 'mongod --help' for more
>   information

Comment: can you try running simple `mongod --bind_ip=$IP --nojournal` do you still get the error?

Comment: yes, i tried doing that too. But that too is giving me the same error. @AbdeenM.

Comment: try running `mongod --bind_ip localhost`

Comment: But i'm not running it locally. @AbdeenM

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this problem i deleted parts of the code.

This is the new code:

```
$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --dbpath data --nojournal "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
$ ./mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Like given in the `mongodb --help` section, `--bind_ip arg` is the correct format.

You need to use

```sh
$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip $IP --dbpath data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
$ ./mongod
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work for me.